# What is the best way of display image thumb in android?

Tags: bitmap, imageview

I have created an app in which I download an image from the Internet and display it page by page in activity.

The user requirement is to display the every image thumb at the bottom of the activity.

**so I create the thumb using this code.**

```
/**
     * Method for decode Sampled Bitmap From Resource for thumb image.
     * 
     * @param fileName
     * @param reqWidth
     * @param reqHeight
     * @return Bitmap
     */
    public Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(String fileName,int reqWidth, int reqHeight) 
    {

        String imagePath = fileName;        

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        File imgFile = new File(imagePath);

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath,options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        generalHelperbitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath,options);


        return generalHelperbitmap;
    }
```

**but my question is; is this the best way to dispaly the thumb?**

Is there another way to download the main image and display these pages with new **smallwidth** and new **smallheight**?

In this question I download the image from the Internet and decode in to bitmap and display this image page by page.

Can someone please tell me which one is the best way to display **image and thumb**?

When I download an image list greater then 50 then the app's performance is slow, and when I change my device orientation then the app's performance is even slower.

Any help is appreciated!